# generating vector from text data for KMeans using spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

I am new to Spark and Machine Learning. I am trying to cluster using KMeans Some data like

```
1::Hi How are you
2::I am fine, how about you
```

In the data, separator is :: and Actual text to cluster is second column that has text data.
After reading on the spark official page and numerous articles I have written following code but I am not able to generate the vector to provide as input to KMeans.train step.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val sc = new SparkContext("local", "test") 

val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer}

val rawData = sc.textFile("data/mllib/KM.txt").map(line => line.split("::")(1))

val sentenceData = rawData.toDF("sentence")

val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words")

val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)

val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("rawFeatures").setNumFeatures(20)

val featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)

val clusters = KMeans.train(featurizedData, 2, 10)
```

I am getting following error

```
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
       val clusters = KMeans.train(featurizedData, 2, 10)
```

Please suggest how to process input data for KMeans

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I get it working after replacing the following code.

```
val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("rawFeatures").setNumFeatures(20)

val featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)

val clusters = KMeans.train(featurizedData, 2, 10)
```

With

```
val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setNumFeatures(1000).setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol).setOutputCol("features")

val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setFeaturesCol("features").setPredictionCol("prediction")

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, kmeans))
```